# Connecting S3 as a SMB share

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, smbfs

I currently have a regular on Premise SMB file share using a storage NAS. I want to delete the NAS all-in-all and use S3 service. I want to know is it possible to have it attach to say my Windows File Server as a network drive. Then from there redirect clients documents, photo, and videos to a space on the S3 drive. But have my File Server handle the connection to the S3 service?

So it would act as it does now really. When you go to `\\fileserver\$user-redir\[name]` it will direct to the user profile but there profile is really on an S3 drive.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The [AWS Storage Gateway for Files](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/file/) fills most of your requirements. It runs as a VM, so you probably can't run it on a standard NAS.

You can probably mount S3 directly to a PC, rather than via the NAS.

(A year later) You could also look at [MSP360 (CloudBerry) Drive](https://www.msp360.com/drive/amazon-s3.aspx), which makes S3 look like a network drive to Windows.

Comment: Do you know if I can chose the share name or it is forced to be the bucket name? Thanks

Comment: I don't know, sorry.